# How to find all zeros of a function using numpy (and scipy)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have a function `f(x)` defined between `a` and `b`. This function can have many zeros, but also many asymptotes. I need to retrieve **all** the zeros of this function. What is the best way to do it?

Actually, my strategy is the following:

1. I evaluate my function on a given number of points
2. I detect whether there is a change of sign
3. I find the zero between the points that are changing sign
4. I verify if the zero found is really a zero, or if this is an asymptote

   ```
   U = numpy.linspace(a, b, 100) # evaluate function at 100 different points
   c = f(U)
   s = numpy.sign(c)
   for i in range(100-1):
       if s[i] + s[i+1] == 0: # oposite signs
           u = scipy.optimize.brentq(f, U[i], U[i+1])
           z = f(u)
           if numpy.isnan(z) or abs(z) > 1e-3:
               continue
           print('found zero at {}'.format(u))
   ```

This algorithm seems to work, except I see two potential problems:

1. It will not detect a zero that doesn't cross the x axis (for example, in a function like `f(x) = x**2`) However, I don't think it can occur with the function I'm evaluating.
2. If the discretization points are too far, there could be more that one zero between them, and the algorithm could fail finding them.

Do you have a better strategy (still efficient) to find all the zeros of a function?

---

I don't think it's important for the question, but for those who are curious, I'm dealing with characteristic equations of wave propagation in optical fiber. The function looks like (where `V` and `ell` are previously defined, and `ell` is an positive integer):

```
def f(u):
    w = numpy.sqrt(V**2 - u**2)

    jl = scipy.special.jn(ell, u)
    jl1 = scipy.special.jnjn(ell-1, u)
    kl = scipy.special.jnkn(ell, w)
    kl1 = scipy.special.jnkn(ell-1, w)

    return jl / (u*jl1) + kl / (w*kl1)
```

Comment: as a math quibble, I wold have used 'divergence' where you use 'asymptote'.

Comment: Can you also provide a bit more detail about what kind of function you are dealing with? for example, this simply can't be done for `sin(1/x)` in the region around `x=0`.

Comment: @tcaswell I'm not sure what is the right word in English. What I mean is that f(x-) -> -inf and f(x+) -> inf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see with this is if you can actually find *all* roots --- as have already been mentioned in comments, this is not always possible. If you are sure that your function is not completely pathological (`sin(1/x)` was already mentioned), the next one is what's your tolerance to missing a root or several of them. Put differently, it's about to what length you are prepared to go to make sure you did not miss any --- to the best of my knowledge, there is no general method to isolate all the roots for you, so you'll have to do it yourself. What you show is a reasonable first step already. A couple of comments:

- Brent's method is indeed a good choice here.
- First of all, deal with the divergencies.  Since in your function you have Bessels in the denominators, you can first solve for *their roots* -- better look them up in e.g., Abramovitch and Stegun ([Mathworld link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionZeros.html)). This will be a better than using an ad hoc grid you're using.
- What you can do, once you've found two roots or divergencies, `x_1` and `x_2`, run the search again in the interval `[x_1+epsilon, x_2-epsilon]`. Continue until no more roots are found (Brent's method is guaranteed to converge to *a* root, provided there is one).
- If you cannot enumerate all the divergencies, you might want to be a little more careful in verifying a candidate is indeed a divergency: given `x` don't just check that `f(x)` is large, check that, e.g. `|f(x-epsilon/2)| > |f(x-epsilon)|` for several values of `epsilon`  (1e-8, 1e-9, 1e-10, something like that).
- If you want to make sure you don't have roots which simply touch zero, look for the extrema of the function, and for each extremum, `x_e`, check the value of `f(x_e)`.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you limited to `numpy`? Scipy has a package that does exactly what you want:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html

One lesson I've learned: numerical programming is hard, so don't do it :)

---

Anyway, if you're dead set on building the algorithm yourself, the doc page on `scipy` I linked (takes forever to load, btw) gives you a list of algorithms to start with. One method that I've used before is to discretize the function to the degree that is necessary for your problem. (That is, tune \delta x so that it is much smaller than the characteristic size in your problem.) This lets you look for features of the function (like changes in sign). AND, you can compute the derivative of a line segment (probably since kindergarten) pretty easily, so your discretized function has a well-defined first derivative. Because you've tuned the dx to be smaller than the characteristic size, you're guaranteed not to miss any features of the function that are important for your problem.

If you want to know what "characteristic size" means, look for some parameter of your function with units of length or 1/length. That is, for some function f(x), assume x has units of length and f has no units. Then look for the things that multiply x. For example, if you want to discretize cos(\pi x), the parameter that multiplies x (if x has units of length) must have units of 1/length. So the characteristic size of cos(\pi x) is 1/\pi. If you make your discretization much smaller than this, you won't have any issues. To be sure, this trick won't always work, so you may need to do some tinkering.

Comment: The reference you give is about a multidimentional solver. My problem is only one dimension. Why do you say I'm not using `scipy`? `scipy.optimize.brentq` is a scipy function...

Comment: Well, I don't know about the `scipy` dev community, but if I were writing a multi-dimensional solver, I'd make sure I could handle the N=1 case first. You're not using scipy because you're trying to find the roots by hand, instead of using their built in method. So, unless you MEAN to reinvent the wheel, I'd read their doc a bit closer, and see how you can leverage their work to solve your problem.

Comment: I don't agree. Zero finding functions like `brentq` need and interval [a,b] where sign(f(a)) != sign(f(b)) and where f is continuous. I'm not finding the root by hand, I'm just guessing the right interval to start searching.

Comment: I guess I must be missing something. How is your problem not exactly like Small Problem -> Examples in the doc I linked? Also, I think you're going to find it difficult to find a numerical algorithm that guarantees that you've found all the zeroes of a function on the range (-\infty, \infty). Are you implying that `brentq` can't find the roots of cos(x) between 0 and 2*pi? That seems odd...

Comment: The Small Problem example still is a multidimentional problem. My problem is different because I need to find **all** the roots of my function, on a given interval. `brentq` would fail in the interval [0,2*pi] because the signs of the cos function are the same at those two points. You'd need to use [0,pi] interval instead.

Comment: I dunno---the Small problem in the doc is exactly a one dimensional problem. Is your claim that cos(x) is a multidimensional function? The second sentence at the top of the page is "These solvers find x for which F(x) = 0. Both x and F can be multidimensional." This implies that F can also be one dimensional. Do you disagree?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24538/discussion-between-charles-brunet-and-bendundee)

Answer (score 2):

I found out it's relatively easy to implement your own root finder using the [scipy.optimize.fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).

- Idea: Find any zeroes from interval `(start, stop)` and stepsize `step` by calling the `fsolve` repeatedly with changing `x0`. Use relatively small stepsize to find *all*  the roots.
- Can only search for zeroes in one dimension (other dimensions must be fixed). If you have other needs, I would recommend using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for calculating the analytical solution.
- Note: It may not *always* find *all* the zeroes, but I saw it giving relatively good results. I put the code also to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/np-8/88713c0727af473bc8ac990811f0a446), which I will update if needed.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Defined below
r = RootFinder(1, 20, 0.01)
args = (90, 5)
roots = r.find(f, *args)
print("Roots: ", roots)

# plot results
u = np.linspace(1, 20, num=600)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(u, f(u, *args))
ax.scatter(roots, f(np.array(roots), *args), color="r", s=10)
ax.grid(color="grey", ls="--", lw=0.5)
plt.show()
```

#### Example output:

```
Roots:  [ 2.84599497  8.82720551 12.38857782 15.74736542 19.02545276]
```

[image]

zoom-in:
[image]

#### RootFinder definition

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


class RootFinder:
    def __init__(self, start, stop, step=0.01, root_dtype="float64", xtol=1e-9):

        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.step = step
        self.xtol = xtol
        self.roots = np.array([], dtype=root_dtype)

    def add_to_roots(self, x):

        if (x < self.start) or (x > self.stop):
            return  # outside range
        if any(abs(self.roots - x) < self.xtol):
            return  # root already found.

        self.roots = np.append(self.roots, x)

    def find(self, f, *args):
        current = self.start

        for x0 in np.arange(self.start, self.stop + self.step, self.step):
            if x0 < current:
                continue
            x = self.find_root(f, x0, *args)
            if x is None:  # no root found.
                continue
            current = x
            self.add_to_roots(x)

        return self.roots

    def find_root(self, f, x0, *args):

        x, _, ier, _ = fsolve(f, x0=x0, args=args, full_output=True, xtol=self.xtol)
        if ier == 1:
            return x[0]
        return None
```

#### Test function

The `scipy.special.jnjn` does not exist anymore, but I created similar test function for the case.

```
def f(u, V=90, ell=5):
    w = np.sqrt(V ** 2 - u ** 2)

    jl = scipy.special.jn(ell, u)
    jl1 = scipy.special.yn(ell - 1, u)
    kl = scipy.special.kn(ell, w)
    kl1 = scipy.special.kn(ell - 1, w)

    return jl / (u * jl1) + kl / (w * kl1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this problem to solve equations like f(z)=0 where f was an holomorphic function. I wanted to be sure not to miss any zero and finally developed an algorithm which is based on the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle).

It helps to find the exact number of zeros lying in a complex domain. Once you know the number of zeros, it is easier to find them. There are however two concerns which must be taken into account :

- Take care about multiplicity : when solving (z-1)^2 = 0, you'll get two zeros as z=1 is counting twice
- If the function is meromorphic (thus contains poles), each pole reduce the number of zero and break the attempt to count them.