# Trying to find all ordered pairs (x,y) such that f(x,y) = 0 and g(x,y) = 0; i.e., I'm trying to find the roots of a multi-variable function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

**Note:** I originally had chi = 1 but I've changed it to chi = 0 (This is the simpler case).

My equations f(x,y) and g(x,y) come from the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

def stress(X,Y):
    chi = 0
    F = 1
    a = 1
    c = (1.0*a)/(np.sqrt(np.power(X,2)+np.power(Y,2))*1.0)
    A = 0.5*(1 - c**2. + (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    B = 0.5*(1 - c**2. - (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    C = 0.5*(1 + c**2. - (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    D = 0.5*(1 + c**2. + (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    E = 0.5*((1 + 2*c**2. - 3*c**4.)*np.sin(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))

    f = 1.0*F*c**2 + (A-1.0*chi*B) # Radial stress
    g = -1.*F*c**2 + (C - 1.0*chi*D) # Tangential stress
    return f,g

def f(X,Y):
    return stress(X,Y)[0]
def g(X,Y):
    return stress(X,Y)[1]

def find_points(X_max,Y_max,X_steps,Y_steps):
    Xs = np.linspace(-X_max,X_max,X_steps)
    Ys = np.linspace(-Y_max,Y_max,Y_steps)

    radials = f(Xs,Ys)
    tangentials = g(Xs,Ys)

    return radials, tangentials

find_points(10,10,100,100)
```

This returns arrays of values for f and g.

I would like to find all of the (X,Y) ordered pairs where both f(X,Y) = 0 and g(X,Y) = 0. I was looking at different scipy packages and I couldn't find anything that seem to work for a multi-variable function like this. Also, my answers right now are being returned in arrays, so could I use something like np.where()? The problem with this is that because I'm storing exact values, I don't necessarily ever see f(x,y) or g(x,y) explicitly equal zero. My end goal is to plot these points. Also, does what I did so far make sense with the Xs and Ys as linspaces over these ranges?

Thank you

Update: I went back and wrote up a little script using a guideline I found on a somewhat similar question see [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python?rq=1). I used scipy.optimize.

```
from scipy import optimize

def equations(p):
    X, Y = p
    a = 1
    F = 1
    chi = 0
    c = (1.0*a)/(np.sqrt(np.power(X,2)+np.power(Y,2))*1.0)
    A = 0.5*(1 - c**2. + (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    B = 0.5*(1 - c**2. - (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    C = 0.5*(1 + c**2. - (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    D = 0.5*(1 + c**2. + (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))

    f = 1.0*F*c**2 + (A-1.0*chi*B) # Radial stress
    g = -1.*F*c**2 + (C - 1.0*chi*D) # Tangential stress
    return (f,g)

X, Y =  optimize.fsolve(equations, (1, 1))

print equations((X, Y))
```

This requires me to put in different initial guesses to get different (X,Y) roots. It would be awesome if somehow I could solve all of the solutions. Also, the answers I'm getting seem kind of off. 
Thanks again.

**Note:**
The original equations, before I converted them to Cartesian coordinates, were as follows:

```
def stress(R,theta):
    chi = 0
    F = 1
    a = 1
    c = (1.0*a)/(R*1.0)
    A = 0.5*(1 - c**2. + (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    B = 0.5*(1 - c**2. - (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    C = 0.5*(1 + c**2. - (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    D = 0.5*(1 + c**2. + (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    E = 0.5*((1 + 2*c**2. - 3*c**4.)*np.sin(2*theta))

    f = 1.0*F*c**2. + (A-1.0*chi*B) # Radial stress
    g = -1.0*F*c**2. + (C-1.0*chi*D) # Tangential stress
    return f,g
```

Maybe this will help sort out some of the confusion with the arctan(Y/X) aspect of the equation.

Comment: There's a `root` function in `scipy.optimize` which can find roots of a set of multivariable equation but I think you have to compute the jacobian yourself. There's a nice example here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#sets-of-equations

Comment: @Azad I've been looking into this for a while. Would you like to elaborate in an answer, or shall I have at it?

Comment: @AndrasDeak OK I'll post an answer

Comment: @AndrasDeak Actually I changed my mind computing this jacobian will take some time

Comment: @Azad OK, then I'll look into it:)

Comment: @Azad See my edit above.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Please see above edit.

Comment: Have a look at the links on the right: [some are promising](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878110/how-to-find-all-zeros-of-a-function-using-numpy-and-scipy?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Azad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396966/trying-to-find-all-ordered-pairs-x-y-such-that-fx-y-0-and-gx-y-0-i-e#comment54595484_33396966) has already noted in a comment, you probably need [`scipy.optimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) to do the bulk of the work for you. Specifically, either [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve) or [`scipy.optimize.root`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root). As the latter seems more general, I'll demonstrate that. Since it can use multiple methods, have a look at the help.

Both of these functions are capable of finding roots for functions mapping from R^n to R^m, i.e. multivariate vector-valued functions. If you consider your `stress` function, that's exactly what you have: it maps from R^2 to R^2. For clarity, you could even define it as

```
def stress2(Rvec):
    X,Y=Rvec
    chi = 1
    F = 1
    a = 1
    c = (1.0*a)/(np.sqrt(np.power(X,2)+np.power(Y,2))*1.0)
    A = 0.5*(1 - c**2. + (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    B = 0.5*(1 - c**2. - (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    C = 0.5*(1 + c**2. - (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    D = 0.5*(1 + c**2. + (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    E = 0.5*((1 + 2*c**2. - 3*c**4.)*np.sin(2*np.arctan(Y/X)))
    f = 1.0*F*c**2 + (A-1.0*chi*B) # Radial stress
    g = -1.*F*c**2 + (C - 1.0*chi*D) # Tangential stress
    return f,g
```

Now, with this definition you can simply call

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
sol=opt.root(stress2,[0.5,0.5])
```

wich will try to find a zero starting from `[0.5,0.5]`. Note that the root of the vector-valued function is exactly where both of its components are zero, which is what you're after.

The return [`OptimizeResult`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult) looks like this:

```
In [224]: sol
Out[224]: 
  status: 1
 success: True
     qtf: array([  2.94481987e-09,   4.76366933e-25])
    nfev: 47
       r: array([ -7.62669534e-06,   7.62669532e-06,   2.16965211e-21])
     fun: array([  2.25125258e-10,  -2.25125258e-10])
       x: array([ 167337.87789902,  167337.87786433])
 message: 'The solution converged.'
    fjac: array([[-0.70710678,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]])
```

It has a bunch of information. First of all, `sol.status` will tell you if it converged successfully. This is the most important output: your root and the possibility of finding it *very sensitively* depends on your starting point. If you try a starting point where `X=0` or `Y=0` in your example, you'll see that it has difficulties finding a root.

If you *do* have a root, `sol.x` will tell you the coordinates, and `sol.fun` will tell you the value of your function (near 0 if `sol.status==1`).

Now, as you also noticed, each call will tell you at most a single root. To find multiple roots, you can't avoid searching for them. You can do this by going over an `X,Y` grid of your choice, starting `root/fsolve` from there, and checking whether the search succeeded. If it did: store the values for post-processing.

Unfortunately, finding the zeros of a nonlinear multivariate function is far from easy, so you have to get your hands dirty sooner or later.

### Update

You're in for some trouble. Consider:

```
v=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(v,v)

fig = plt.figure()
hc=plt.contourf(X,Y,stress2([X,Y])[0].clip(-1,1),levels=np.linspace(-1,1,20))
plt.contour(X,Y,stress2([X,Y])[0].clip(-1,1),levels=[0],color=(1,0,0))
plt.colorbar(hc)
```

and the same for the other function. Here's how the `x` and `y` components of your function look like, respectively:

[image: x component] [image: y component]

They both have zeros along some hyperbolic-like curves. *Which seem to be identical*. This figure strongly suggests that there is a *line* of points where your function is zero: both components. This is as bad as it can get for numerical root-finding algorithms, as there are no clear-cut (isolated) zeroes.

I suggest checking your function on paper for the case of `X==Y`, you might indeed see that your function disappears there, at least asymptotically.

### Update2

You added the original, polar form of your function. While I can't see where you went wrong (apart from using `np.arctan` instead of `np.arctan2`, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem), I tried plotting your polar function:

```
def stress_polar(Rvec):
    R,theta=Rvec
    chi = 0
    F = 1
    a = 1
    c = (1.0*a)/(R*1.0)                                   
    A = 0.5*(1 - c**2. + (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    B = 0.5*(1 - c**2. - (1 - 4*c**2 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    C = 0.5*(1 + c**2. - (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    D = 0.5*(1 + c**2. + (1 + 3*c**4.)*np.cos(2*theta))
    E = 0.5*((1 + 2*c**2. - 3*c**4.)*np.sin(2*theta))
    f = 1.0*F*c**2. + (A-1.0*chi*B)
    g = -1.0*F*c**2. + (C-1.0*chi*D)
    return f,g

v1=np.linspace(0.01,10,100)
v2=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
R,theta=np.meshgrid(v1,v2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax=plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
hc=plt.contourf(theta,R,stress_polar([R,theta])[0].clip(-1,1),levels=np.linspace(-1,1,20))
plt.contour(theta,R,stress_polar([R,theta])[0].clip(-1,1),levels=[0],color=(1,0,0))
plt.colorbar(hc)
```

and the same for the tangential component. Note that the polar plot needs to get `theta` first, then `R`. The result:

[image: radial component] [image: tangential component]

this shows a quite different picture, with a finite support for the zeros of the radial component. Now, I've never used polar plots before in matplotlib, so it's equally possible that I messed something up during plotting. But it might be worth looking at the `A,B,C,D` parameters that are computed by your polar and Cartesian functions, to make sure they compute the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! This is a handy little bit of code. My only concern is sol.x. Does that not seem a little suspect that the coordinate pair for this example is approx. (167337.8779,167337.8779)? These values seem way too large also. Maybe my intuition is wrong though. @AndrasDeak

Comment: @Ned Well, yeah, that's weird, but it also depends on your function. Check out a lot of starting points. That `arctan(Y/X)` by itself seems a bit difficult for me. Plus all those trigonometric functions are periodic, possibly creating a bunch of roots.

Comment: That is really bad news. I included the original forms of the equations as functions of (R,theta). Hopefully this will clarify that arctan(Y/X) part as well as some other aspects of it. Did I convert to Cartesian coordinates correctly? @AndrasDeak

Comment: I ran some numbers and you seem to be correct. After a certain point, when X==Y, f = g = 0. At X = 1 Y =1, f = 0.5 and g = -0.5. By X = 3, Y = 3; f = 0.056 and g = -0.056. They begin to converge very quickly to zero after this. @Andras

Comment: @Ned I updated my answer. 1. I screwed up the original plots, so the second component has a bit different zeros as I thought. But the asymptotic behaviour you found is still the same. 2. I added polar plots with your polar function. If I didn't screw *this* up, then there is indeed a problem with your transformation, but I can't find what it is... Anyway, use `arctan2(y,x)` instead of `arctan(y/x)` in such cases, that's more safe and general.

Comment: @Ned I just noticed that you changed `chi` along the way. Bad idea. This probably explains the difference between the two sets of plots, but I don't have time right now to make sure.

Comment: I apologizing for not making the switch on chi more proclaimed. This change definitely accounts for the change in the two plots that you produced. Your contour plots are amazing. I really appreciate all of your help. You've helped me out a ton. I wish that I could upvote your answer but apparently I need a higher reputation before my upvote goes into effect. Thanks again @Andras

Comment: @Ned It's OK, neither of us were careful enough:) I'm glad I could help. You can still mark my answer as accepted if you feel that it solved your problem.