# Find all roots of a function in python

Tags: python, numpy

Given `x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)` and given the function `y = (x+2)*(x-1)*(x-2)`, I wish to get all the values of `x` when `y==0`.

I tried with `x[y==0]`, but it only returns this: `array([1.])`, while I expected to get `[-2, 1, 2]`.

Comment: What is `x`?  `x = np.arange(-50, 50)` and `y = (x+2)*(x-1)*(x-2)` would give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry @BradSolomon, I totally forgot to state `x` on my question. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Your issue is that `-2` and `2` are not represented in your x, the closest are `2.03030303` and `-2.03030303`

Comment: possible ducplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878110/how-to-find-all-zeros-of-a-function-using-numpy-and-scipy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 from sympy import *
 x=Symbol('x')
 ans=solve((x+2)*(x-1)*(x-2),x)
 print(ans)  #output-> [-2,1,2]
```