# Find the root of a function in python

Tags: python, scipy

I need to find the root of some functions in python, for which I have only numerical data, not the actual functional form. I tried to use `scipy.optimize.root`, but I am getting some weird result. Here is a minimal code reproducing the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
from scipy import optimize

def func(x):
    return (x-4)*(np.exp(x)+1)

x = np.random.rand(1000)*10
y = func(x)
data = np.column_stack((x,y))

p = data[:,0].argsort()
x = data[:,0][p]
y = data[:,1][p]

cs = CubicSpline(x, y)

sol = optimize.root(cs, [0], method='hybr')

print(sol.x)
```

The output of the code is `-5.42024365` which is obviously not a root of the function I picked. If I try `cs(-5.42024365)` I get `-0.00305901` (the initial data is randomly generated, so that value will change a bit, but it is clearly not zero). If I try `cs(4)` I get `-4.46575001e-07` which looks more like a root (and it is actually the root I am trying to find). What am I doing wrong. Why is `scipy.optimize.root` not giving me the right root, even for this simple problem? Thank you!

Comment: You have a function more than one root. It is not always possible to find all roots, eg sin(1/x). The gradient descent found a local minimum for you. If you choose another starting point it will find another one. Here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878110/how-to-find-all-zeros-of-a-function-using-numpy-and-scipy

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins uh...yeah, but (x-4)*(np.exp(x)+1) has only one root...

Comment: Well, you either need to fit it with something else rather than a spline. Or use something like brentq to search in your interval of interest

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Here's your function. It has just found the second root.

Comment: I think you plotted the wrong function. That is not (x-4)*(np.exp(x)+1)

Comment: This is the cs(arange(-10, 10)). The spline of which you're searching roots of

Comment: oh so the problem is that the cs is not giving the right function?

Comment: Splines are used for interpolation. They are no good for extrapolation.

Comment: However if I run sol = optimize.root(func, [0], method='hybr'), so using the actual function, I get as the result -1.515625, which also is not the real root...

Comment: You might find some inspiration here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range They suggest: equidistant grid, differential equation, and RootSearch heuristics.